# Resetting the HC-06 Bluetooth module with Arduino Uno?

Tags: c, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

This is my first post on Stackoverflow so I hope you can answer my question.

I am fairly new to Arduino and I accidentally changed the baudrate and name of my HC-06 Bluetooth module with the following code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 4); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  //Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  mySerial.begin(9600);
  //mySerial.begin(57600);
  //mySerial.begin(115200);    //if you change the baud and want to re-run this sketch, make sure this baud rate matches the new rate.

  delay(1000);
  mySerial.print("AT");
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.print("AT+VERSION");
  delay(1000);

  //mySerial.print("AT+PIN1234"); // Set pin to 1234  was 1342
  //delay(1000);

  //mySerial.print("AT+NAMEJY-MCU-HC06"); // Set the name to JY-MCU-HC06
  //delay(1000);

  //mySerial.print("AT+BAUD4"); // Set baudrate to 9600
  //mySerial.print("AT+BAUD7"); // Set baudrate to 57600
  mySerial.print("AT+BAUD8"); // Set baudrate to 115200
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
  Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
  mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Now I'm unable to revert back to the default settings (baudrate 9600 and name HC-06) and I don't how to fix this.

I tried entering serial AT commands but I get no response. I also made sure the HC-06 module is not paired with any other device, but still no response. I also tried different sources and terminals besides the Arduino Serial monitor, like:

http://www.hobbyist.co.nz/?q=bluetooth-module-device

http://42bots.com/tutorials/hc-06-bluetooth-module-datasheet-and-configuration-with-arduino/

And more...

So my question is as follows: How am I supposed to revert the changes I made to the HC-06 Bluetooth module, preferably back to baudrate 9600?

Thank you in advance.

-F

Comment: Probably you can use a terminal program and try to send AT commands on various baudrates until it responds. Then change back to 9600 through the terminal program.

Comment: I did as you suggested using Tera Term, no response unfortunately..

Comment: Did your switch your Tera Term to 115200 bauds after sending the `mySerial.print("AT+BAUD8");` command ? Did you saw the `OK115200` ?

Comment: No, I did not receive any confirmation of it changing. However, after uploading the sketch, the name of the module changed so I assume the baudrate changed as well. My assumption comes from the fact that I could monitor data on the Android application: S2 Terminal for Bluetooth, on my Android phone. Now I just get weird signals like; �, so I assume this is because of the changed baudrate?

Comment: What did you observe when switching your Tera Term to 115200 bauds ? Enter "AT"+<Return> to see answer.

Comment: I don't receive any answer when I enter AT commands from the terminal, do you think the pins should be connected to digital 3,4 (like in the sketch), or to the rx,tx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I feel so dumb...

Apparently I set the baudrate to 57600, not 115200... So now I was able to change the baudrate and name through the 57600 baudrate.

Well, I wont forget how it works now after this :P. Thank you all for your time and patience.

-F

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using hardware serial instead of software serial and see if that works?

Note: In my experience using the HC bluetooth module with the arduino hardware serial, in order to get proper sketch uploads, you must unplug either the power or the tx/rx of the HC-06 from the Arduino, otherwise it will interfere.

Also, you may want to comment out

```
mySerial.print("AT+BAUD8"); // Set baudrate to 115200
```

and uncomment

```
//mySerial.print("AT+BAUD4"); // Set baudrate to 9600
```

when you send the command you should get something like this:

From Host controller:

> AT+BAUD3

Response

> OK4800

[Secondary Datasheet For Reference](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FQ1/CUVZ/HXA9PUVQ/FQ1CUVZHXA9PUVQ.pdf)

On the datasheet there is a reset pin on 11. (diagram on page 2)

Also, there's a reset command:

> AT+RESET Reset Device

Comment: I don't know how to use the Hardware Serial with the Arduino, does it work the same way as the Software Serial? e.g.  `#include <HardwareSerial.h> HardwareSerial mySerial(3,4);`?
Also, I don't receive any response when I enter any AT command line, do you think the pins should be connected to the 3,4 pins (like in the sketch) or the rx, tx pins?

Comment: I also don't know how to use the reset pin, do I just connect something to it long enough that it should reset automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your baud rate beyond 8(115200), is hard to go back to 9600 or other usable one as commputers mostly don't handle frequencies that high.

There is an assembler trick made by Doctor Yoda at instructables.com based on ATMEGA328P-PU (for example arduino UNO) that will probably help to fake a serial connection in such a high frequencies. Based on his work, I did this page to generate an arduino script that may recover your AT connection to your HC-06.

Read Doctor Yoda's post first.

https://tools.krum.com.ar/save_your_hc-06/